# Searching one excel spreadsheet based off a key of another

Tags: excel, database, spreadsheet

I have one excel spreadsheet that contains a row of keys such as 1649567, 1649593, 1650126, 1651166, 1655794, 1656561. I have a second spreadsheet that contains a list of keys including the keys from the first spreadsheet. I need to filter the second spreadsheet based on the keys in the first spreadsheet. There are thousands of keys. How would I go about this?

Comment: Use an if() with a match() to match a value on the second sheet to see if it occurrs in the first - if it does label it double.

Comment: Easy with a *VBA* macro................is this approach okay ??

Answer (score 0):

Build an array from the row of keys and use that as the Criteria1 parameter in AutoFilter with Operator:=xlFilterValues. Text-that-looks-like-numbers works better than true numbers in an array with xlFilterValues.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim vals As Variant, i As Long

    With Worksheets("sheet2")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            ReDim vals(1 To .Cells.Count)
            For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
                vals(i) = .Cells(i).Text
            Next i
        End With
    End With

    With Worksheets("sheet3")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=vals, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```